# What happened with "startWith" in ReactiveCocoa 5.0?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

Anyone know what become of the "startWith" function?

I trying to learn reactivecocoa using a book that worked with 4.x version. The example used startWith to force a value for a datePicker control.

Answer (score 1):

There are now versions `startWithValues`, `startWithFailed`, `startWithCompleted` and `startWithInterrupted` in the case where you only care for one specific type of events.

If you need more or all events, use the version `start` that takes an `Observer` and the switch over the event

```
producer.start { event in
    switch event {
    case let .value(value):
        // Handle value
    case let .failed(err):
        // Handle error
    case .completed:
        // Handle completed
    case .interrupted:
        // Handle interrupted
    }
}
```